# bootstrap 3 responsiveness for xs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

**Goal:** when viewed on phone, the image gallery shows just one column of images

**Whats happening:** works fine at lg, md, sm, but then below 767 pixels keeps the 'sm' setting.  I know this has been addressed in bootstrap 4, but I want to try and understand why its not working with version 3 before i go through and start making updates using v4.

This is just a snippet as I have lots of images in here, but this is inside a div with row class and inside a container class as well.

I've tried including col-xs-12; col-xs; not including it and also setting the Css to 100% width, flex, etc.. (things I found in other posts- I tried, but they didn't work for my case)

```html
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/YwlgEiwXej42zA7V_BuCh_g6eozBIe6LZk4srhomMKIkbMyYngyBZ-08wm9SV-vL_piHBvWsXBLOppMG5HW3K8vJk_1OK2TpkeP0OmN0PSMPBLj5fPi_wCxHqTagaE3u-XmBcMHutSkEJGhB00IQCQogAEtAPHFhJYc0Jv_1IQc8-waSc3mUA_mBdghlnoLtRgrlMDnew7JaXwgMaG-n1BaBfwPny7sHwNqaD7rXtbV8KSY7vxS9QSWmHTcp-qHEYd9J-kKaoQsVHhu6E80vMMvhNEIYb0B6oQYwIHpnBAJNYFYeQ1edv0JSL6KGI1EXhRTfhCt-4YqUAjt8DVUF2anFJ2nQEZw9fOzb7q4lHxuPl8eh4yMbVcwAnQ1a09OwCI8FB2mTvqOZUr7Jv0xhDRkz88OyVFRrwW3Q1Zh495OCWKlLHD12hg5In-XsqKOjOu8IAAP9WSQpmbNi31TGo-dmulsnOodkiTB8ChxMiKc_K5uTc8dSMWpLklqkcdhk8uaTqkFP6L3jC2bsSXZSOcIUx8CIm-SE8r8FXQoaJKpRbQ-pekPa2PhsxkL9rn9OsBi4QmBmyo5VwpTLT9HgaNabmoTkHfZtWCxpOB1bUxq3rmeIndW7NbcoKHowszRqtYY6R4zhviJZhM0vp3PJERiUv-EwQZIk_zPBjVdEKyZWxQEh5s-yQ75IU_YfxBxhfh7FPyiRTQty2spcUf0HrxWE96-BbqEX9EEQJAWIi5EnProNLd8VDTwS=w743-h784-no"
        alt="momo">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Col-xs** in Bootstrap 3 is applied for extra small screens, and that works fine, so far as the logic goes. You need to find some of your other css rules that overrides this, and breaks the Bootstrap rules. The problem must not stand with Bootstrap itself.

Moreover, why not upgrading to Bootstrap 4, and keeping updated. Keeping updated with plugins and scripts is a must-do practice, I assume. In Bootstrap 4, **col** without -sm, -md, -lg is applied for extra small screens. col-xs has been deprecated in favor of col-. In fact col-12 is equal to col-xs-12 from previous versions of Bootstrap.
if you want to check your Bootstrap grid system, you can use the following code:

```
<div class="alert alert-info">
<div class="d-none d-xl-block font-weight-bold">X-LARGE (XL)</div>
<div class="d-none d-lg-block d-xl-none font-weight-bold">LARGE (LG)</div>
<div class="d-none d-md-block d-lg-none font-weight-bold">MEDIUM (M)</div>
<div class="d-none d-sm-block d-md-none font-weight-bold">SMALL (SM)</div>
<div class="d-block d-sm-none alert font-weight-bold">X-SMALL (Defaut)</div></div>
```

Comment: i was missing a meta tag with the viewport is why it wasn't working.  my basic html template was bad :(  thank you though!